# Detect origin tab, if any, that opened new tab/window

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

For an upcoming version of an add-on I created, I want to detect from which tab, if any, a link was opened in a new tab or window.

My add-on is a zoom add-on, and I want to be able to copy the zoom level of the origin tab if a user opens a link in a new tab or window.

I've already figured out how to detect the opener if a link is opened with  `window.open()` from content-JavaScript (that was fairly easy), however I have no real idea how to figure out if a new tab/window was opened from the context menu (open link in new tab/new window) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click.

To detect whether it was opened from content-Javascript, I use:

```js
const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;

let windowTracker = {
  observe: function( subject, topic, data ) {
    if( 'chrome-document-global-created' == topic && subject instanceof Ci.nsIDOMWindow ) {
      // here I can use subject.opener
    }
  }
}

let observerService = Cc[ '@mozilla.org/observer-service;1' ].getService( Ci.nsIObserverService );
observerService.addObserver( this, 'chrome-document-global-created', false );
```

To detect any possible non-content-JavaScript opener I've tried this in `observe()`:

```js
let windowTracker = {
  observe: function( subject, topic, data ) {
    if( 'chrome-document-global-created' == topic && subject instanceof Ci.nsIDOMWindow ) {
      let topWindow = subject.QueryInterface( Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor )
                             .getInterface( Ci.nsIWebNavigation )
                             .QueryInterface( Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem )
                             .rootTreeItem
                             .QueryInterface( Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor )
                             .getInterface( Ci.nsIDOMWindow );
      // here I tried topWindow.opener, with mixed results
    }
  }
}
```

... but got mixed results.

When I open a link in a new tab or window with the context menu or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click, `topWindow.opener` equals `null`, but if I, for instance, open the Add-ons Manager with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, `topWindow.opener` will be an instance of `ChromeWindow`.

So, it seems I'm kind of on the right track, but not quite, as I'm merely interested in user initiated opening of content links in a new tab or window.

Is what I'm after doable?

In inspecting the source code of Firefox, I've noticed that there might be a method (unless I'm misinterpreting its purpose) that would give me what I am after: [`getOpener()`](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/docshell/base/nsIDocShell.idl#1009) in [`nsIDocShell`](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/docshell/base/nsIDocShell.idl). However, that method is not exposed in the scripting API.

Is there anything similar that I *could* utilize?

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get it working by intercepting [`ChromeWindow.openLinkIn()`](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/base/content/utilityOverlay.js#208) with a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object:

```js
// window is a top level ChromeWindow
window.openLinkIn = new Proxy( window.openLinkIn, {
  apply: function( target, thisArg, argumentsList ) {

    let url    = argumentsList[ 0 ];
    let where  = argumentsList[ 1 ];
    let params = argumentsList.length > 2 ? argumentsList[ 2 ] : {};

    // links opened through the context menu or Ctrl/⌘/Shift+click
    // don't have params.fromChrome = true
    if( !url || !where || params.fromChrome ) {
      return target.apply( thisArg, argumentsList );
    }

    switch( where ) {
      case 'tab':
        // break intentionally omitted
      case 'tabshifted':
        let tabBrowser = window.gBrowser;
        tabBrowser.tabContainer.addEventListener( 'TabOpen', function onTabOpen( event ) {
          tabBrowser.tabContainer.removeEventListener( 'TabOpen', onTabOpen, true );

          let tab = event.target;
          // do something with the new tab
        }, true );

        break;
      case 'window':
        let windowTracker = {
          init: function() {
            observerService.addObserver( this, 'toplevel-window-ready', false );
          },
          destroy: function() {
            observerService.removeObserver( this, 'toplevel-window-ready' );
          },
          observe: function( subject, topic, data ) {
            let self = this;
            let chromeWindow = subject;
            if( 'toplevel-window-ready' == topic && chromeWindow instanceof Ci.nsIDOMWindow ) {
              chromeWindow.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function onChromeWindowDOMContentLoaded( event ) {
                this.removeEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', onChromeWindowDOMContentLoaded, true );

                if( 'navigator:browser' == this.document.documentElement.getAttribute( 'windowtype' ) ) {

                  // do something with the new chromeWindow

                  // destroy the windowTracker
                  self.destroy();
                }
              }, true );

            }
          }
        }
        windowTracker.init();

        break;
    }

    return target.apply( thisArg, argumentsList );
  }
} );
```

PS.: Be sure to clean up and reinstall the original function, of course, when your extension is disabled. You can do this with something like this:

```js
let originalOpenLinkIn = window.openLinkIn;
window.openLinkIn = new Proxy( window.openLinkIn, {
  apply: /* implementation from above */
} );

// then when cleaning up:
window.openLinkIn = originalOpenLinkIn;
```

Answer (score 1):

> however I have no real idea how to figure out if a new tab/window was opened from the context menu (open link in new tab/new window) or Ctrl/⌘/Shift+click.

In such cases, especially if they are opened in a new window, the tab doesn't really have an owner. They're considered equivalent to the user just typing the URL in the address bar.

What you can do is installing a [system event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIEventListenerService#addSystemEventListener%28%29) for bubbling `click`, `contextmenu` and `submit` events on each `window` and check if the target is a form or link and then check their target url. If a newly opened tab's location matches the last clicked/submitted link then it's probably from that previous tab.

Comment: Hey thanks. That's seems like a plan indeed. However, in the meanwhile I've come up with something that's possibly a little more reliable, if somewhat convoluted (it involves intercepting [`ChromeWindow.openLinkIn()`](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/base/content/utilityOverlay.js#208) with a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object). I'll post it as an answer or question edit, later on.